# How to display file size before starting a download?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, download

In Firefox when you click a link to download it, before starting the download it tells you the size of the file you're about to download. Whereas in Chrome it just opens the window asking where to save it but doesn't show you the size. Is there a way to get it to show the total size of the file before you start downloading it?

Comment: While not a solution per se, have you considered using a download manager that shows the file size before downloading _(also provides the added benefit of faster downloads via multiple download streams - there are free ones, however I've used [Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) for over a decade and prefer it due to it's customizability and feature set)_?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers including Chrome don't have the capacity to tell you the size
of a file before executing the download.

However, the webserver that is  serving the file may sometimes return
the file size among the headers returned in the first chunk of the answer
(see [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length)).

To know the file size of a download where the size is not returned
by the webserver, you will have to attempt downloading the file with
a download manager like the
[Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn/related?hl=en).
The download manager will in most cases scan the file size before it
proceeds to do the download.